# What's the classification of tensorlfow's graph node?

Tags: tensorflow

As the Title said, I want to know the classification of tensorflow's graph node?

When I dig into the source code of tensorflow, I notice that the tensorflow runtime will check the the type of node using the following method:

```
422 inline bool IsSource(const Node* node) { return node->IsSource(); }    
423 inline bool IsSink(const Node* node) { return node->IsSink(); }        
424 inline bool IsSwitch(const Node* node) { return node->IsSwitch(); }    
425 inline bool IsMerge(const Node* node) { return node->IsMerge(); }      
426 inline bool IsEnter(const Node* node) { return node->IsEnter(); }      
427 inline bool IsExit(const Node* node) { return node->IsExit(); }        
428 inline bool IsNextIteration(const Node* n) { return n->IsNextIteration(); }
429 inline bool IsLoopCond(const Node* node) { return node->IsLoopCond(); }
430 inline bool IsControlTrigger(const Node* n) { return n->IsControlTrigger(); }
431 inline bool IsSend(const Node* node) { return node->IsSend(); }        
432 inline bool IsRecv(const Node* node) { return node->IsRecv(); }        
433 inline bool IsHostSend(const Node* node) { return node->IsHostSend(); }
434 inline bool IsHostRecv(const Node* node) { return node->IsHostRecv(); }
435                                                                        
436 // True for Nodes that mediate the transfer of values between processes.
437 inline bool IsTransferNode(const Node* n) { return IsSend(n) || IsRecv(n); }
438                                                                        
439 inline bool IsConstant(const Node* node) { return node->IsConstant(); }
440 inline bool IsVariable(const Node* node) { return node->IsVariable(); }
441 inline bool IsIdentity(const Node* node) { return node->IsIdentity(); }
```

For now, I just make sense(I seldom use conditions and loop expression tensorflow provides):

```
inline bool IsSource(const Node* node) { return node->IsSource(); } 
inline bool IsSink(const Node* node) { return node->IsSink(); }
inline bool IsSend(const Node* node) { return node->IsSend(); }
inline bool IsRecv(const Node* node) { return node->IsRecv(); }
inline bool IsHostSend(const Node* node) { return node->IsHostSend(); }
inline bool IsHostRecv(const Node* node) { return node->IsHostRecv(); }
inline bool IsConstant(const Node* node) { return node->IsConstant(); }
inline bool IsVariable(const Node* node) { return node->IsVariable(); }
```

While the rest is difficult for me to understand.
Anyone can help me to understand it? I want to understand the Frame of tensorflow similar to the MIT Tagged-Token machine. Thanks very much!

Comment: This question is too broad to answer and each of the types may merit a stackoverflow question. But if you dig into each of the types, it is not so difficult to find out the answer from the source code. Please let us know which particular one you still can't understand after doing more research into it. Have you read the TensorFlow white paper? TensorFlow website also covers a lot on control flow operations.

Comment: If the question is still too broad to answer, I will try to do more research then ask again:-) thanks.

Comment: I mainly want to understand while tensorflow RunAsyn start,
how does tensorflow's frame work(Continuous dequeue to get the triggered node,executing,building the frame and destroy the frame)